# I need to look up value from dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I have a textbox that I use as a checkbox. I need to see if the value is in the dataset ID field. If it is, I put an "X" in the textbox. How do I do this

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by using an SSRS expression.

Right click on your textbox and go to expression and put the following expression

```
=IIF(isNothing(Fields!ID.Value) OR Fields!ID.Value = "", "", "X")
```

[image]

It checks If the ID field is empty or Null then put blank else put an X.

Remember SSRS is case sensitive. `Fields!ID.Value` is different from `Fields!iD.Value`